# What is the arrow in this instance declaration for?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm reading Real World Haskell and I came across an example wherein a `=>` arrow is used something like this,

```
class Borked a where ...

instance (Borked a, Borked b) => Borked (a, b) where ...
```

How is this different from

```
instance Borked (a, b) where ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that `a` and `b` have to be instances of `Borked` for `(a, b)` to be an instance of `Borked`. So when you try to call one of `Borked`'s methods on a tuple, that's only allowed if the tuple's elements are also instances of `Borked`. This allows you to use `Borked`'s methods on the elements of the tuple in the instance definition.